# Chart js sum of grouped bars

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have 3 different values for each grouped bar. I want to sum those 3 values and display the sum on top of each column - Σ59 and Σ89.

[image]

I'm testing code below which is not working correctly. Instead of column values, number 59 is displayed above every single column.

[image]

```
formatter:  function(value, ctx) {
                        console.log(ctx.chart.data.datasets)
                        let sum = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < ctx.chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
                             sum +=  parseInt(ctx.chart.data.datasets[i].data[0]);

                        }
                        return sum;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25kwbyfj/1/), but i did not format and position the labels as of now, you can do it as you wish.

```
"onComplete": function() {
        var chartInstance = this.chart,
          ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
          ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
          ctx.textAlign = 'center';
          ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
           var sums = [0, 0, 0];
          this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
            var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
            meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
              var data = dataset.data[index];
              ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y);
              sums[index] += data;
            });
            });
          sums.forEach(function(v, i) {
            ctx.fillText(v, 150*(i+1)+(i*50), 40);
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `formatter` is called for each datalabel, meaning for every bar. That's the reason why you get the same value on top of every bar.

Possible solutions would be either to plot an "invisible" bar for the combined value or check inside the `formatter` function if it is called for the centered bar. Then you could use [mulitline labels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/formatting.html#multiline-labels) to create a label which has the value for the current bar and the combined value as well.

Edit:

After thinking about it the easiest way would be to use [mixed](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html) charts. You can just calculate your combined values for each group and add a chart for these values. For example you add a line chart with `showLines: false`.

```
new Chart('myMixedCharts', {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['foo', 'bar'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Value 1",
            data: [12, 5]
          },
          {
            label: "Value 2",
            data: [7, 8]
          },
          {
            label: "Group value",
            data: [19, 13],
            type: "line",
            showLines: false
          }
        ]
    }
});
```

Or as [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0d9L28f/10/)

Comment: Maybe I should leave formatter out and write a callback function for whole column. Do you maybe know where should I put such function?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achive with a callback, but I edited my answer to hint for mixed charts.

Comment: I changed with new pictures where it clearly shows that ony bar chart should be used.

Comment: I don't think there is an option to add a value for a group at the moment, so you should look for a workaround. Maybe you want to add the value to the group label instead to it would be something like "22-18 Σ59".

Comment: Is it possible to add 2 labels and second one - Σ59 add it on chart? That would be the only workaround.

Comment: As I already wrote in my answer I only know about multiline labels, but not about a way to add more than one label for a value.